# how to set postgres primary key fixed lengeth

Tags: postgresql

primary key which is a number and they range anywhere from 1 - 1000 for ex one record's primary key may be 12, and another record's primary key may be 1023. What I need to do is to convert all of the numbers for my primary key in my table to 6 digits, ie 12 becomes 000012, and 1023 becomes 001023.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not need to change the primary key. Use the function [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) in your queries to get the desired format:

```
with my_table(my_numeric_pk) as ( values (12), (1023))

select to_char(my_numeric_pk, 'fm000000') as my_nice_pk
from my_table;

 my_nice_pk 
------------
 000012
 001023
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

use the lpad function (lpad means left pad)

```
SELECT LPAD(1023::TEXT, 6, '0')
-- outputs: 001023
```

store your ids as regular integers, and for output pad them with zeros to make them 6 characters in length.